# jQuery $.value on select > option where there is no value attribute

Tags: jquery, html

Given this HTML code:

```
<select id="menu">
    <option>hi</option>
    <option>bye</option>
</select>
```

This jQuery code:

```
$("#menu option").first().attr("value")
```

returns `hi`, even though there is no `value` attribute on the first option in the menu.

If the `<option>` has a `value` attribute, the `value` attribute is returned, as expected.

How can I have the return value of the above code be `undefined` / something else I can identify? Or could I check if the `value` attribute is set, and only run the above code if it isn't?

Comment: There's an implicit `value` attribute. You probably want to try `:not([value])` in your selector.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `:not([attr])` selector:

```
$("#menu option:not([value])");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NQm54/

I also verified that after changing, the `[value]` still reports as unset, so you continue to receive the same two elements without the `value` attribute.

```
$('#menu').change(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log($("#menu option:not([value])"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NQm54/2/

Comment: I need to check if it is the first option that has no `value`. Based on your post I've tried: `if($("#menu option:not([value])").first() === $("#menu option").first())` with no luck (always `false`). Do you have any ideas? (I've verified in the browser console that the two selectors return the same element)

Comment: OK, I've got it: `($("#menu option:not([value])")[0] === $("#menu option")[0])`. `[0]` (returns element) instead of `.first()` (returns jQuery object). Thanks.

Comment: Sure, see: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NQm54/3/ Use `$.is()`, it's much cleaner and direct.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#menu option:eq(0)").not("[value]").length == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The value defaults to the text value if the value attribute is not set. Just set the attribute value t o some value so you can identify it e.g. an empty string as shown below

```
<select id="menu">
    <option value="">hi</option>
    <option>bye</option>
</select>
```

Then this `$("#menu option").first().attr("value")` will return an empty string

Comment: Thanks, however I am using this in a plugin and therefore have no control over the plugin users' HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var option = document.getElementById("menu").options[0];
if (option.getAttribute("value") !== null) {
console.log("Has value: " + option.value);
 }
else {
console.log("Doesn't have a value.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `$("option:selected", $("#menu")).attr("value");`

If the selected option does not have any value attribute, undefined will be returned which you can capture through !foo